# how to let a function wait for result returned by another function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

i have a function called '**updateProfile()**' which has a condition which is **if(emailChangeConfirm)**, this condition depends upon the value of variable '**emailChangeConfirm**' , this variable gets the value returned by another function called '**updateEmailAllProcessing()**'

the condition '**if(emailChangeConfirm)**' is not getting satisfied at all because compiler is not waiting for the function '**updateEmailAllProcessing()**' to return the value for variable '**emailChangeConfirm**'.

I used **async/await** for this but that is also not working as i want

Desired Solution :

**`function 'updateProfile()' must wait for the function 'updateEmailAllProcessing()' to get the result in 'emailChangeConfirm' so that i can enter in the condition 'if(emailChangeConfirm)'.`**

I am using typescript and working on hybrid app with ionic 3 and angular 5.

```
 async updateProfile(updatedData : Credentials,tarUser : Credentials)
    {
     // console.log(tarUser,'<<--->>>',updatedData)
     let count : number = undefined;
     let emailChangeConfirm : boolean; 
     if(updatedData.name)
     {
       if(tarUser.name != updatedData.name)
       tarUser.name = updatedData.name;
     else
       count++;
    }
    if(updatedData.email)
     {
       if(tarUser.email != updatedData.email)
         {  
        **emailChangeConfirm = await this.updateEmailAllProcessing();**
        console.log(emailChangeConfirm)
        **if(emailChangeConfirm)
        tarUser.email = updatedData.email;**
    }
    else
    count++;
}
if(updatedData.phoneNo)
{
   if(tarUser.phoneNo != updatedData.phoneNo)
    tarUser.phoneNo = updatedData.phoneNo;
    else
    count++;
}

if(updatedData.photoURL)
{
   if(tarUser.photoURL != updatedData.photoURL)
    tarUser.photoURL = updatedData.photoURL;
    else
    count++;
}

if(count)
this.mesService.presentToast('Nothing Updated!!')
else **if(emailChangeConfirm)**
{
  this.dbServe.editUser(tarUser).then(() =>
  {
      console.log("User Edited Successfully with email change too");
      this.authServ.updateEmail(tarUser.email).then(() => 
      {
          console.log('login email updated');
          this.authServ.logout();
      })
      //this.close();
  })
} 
else
{
  this.dbServe.editUser(tarUser).then(() =>
  {
    console.log("User Edited Successfully with No email change");
    this.close();
  })
 }
}

  **async updateEmailAllProcessing()**
  {
    let result : boolean;
    let alert = this.mesService.emailChangeConfirmation();
    alert.present();
    alert.onDidDismiss((data) => {
    console.log('data->',data);
      if(data)
      {
      let alert1 = this.mesService.passwordPrompt();
      alert1.present();
      alert1.onDidDismiss(data1 => 
        {
          console.log('password->',data1);
          if(data1)
          {
            this.authServ.reauthenticateUser(data1).then(() =>
            {
              console.log('User Reauth Done');
              result = true;
            })
          }
          else
          result = false;
        })
      }
      else
      result = false;
     })
    **return result;**
  }
```

Comment: For `async`/`await` to work, you need `updateEmailAllProcessing` to return a promise

Comment: @user184994 yes it is returning a promise check the code, i made `updateEmailAllProcessing` async

Comment: But `let result : boolean;`? So it looks like you're trying to return a boolean

Comment: @user184994 ohh!! so you mean returning a value dosen't make it a promise??

Comment: No, it doesn't. You should wrap the whole thing in a promise, and call `resolve` when you have your value

Comment: thanks @user184994 i am new to promise and observables , can you give me any link or some good source so that i can get command to these concepts.

Comment: please tell me what is happening when i am making a method async ??

Comment: The `async` keyword on it's own does nothing, it just allows us to use the `await` keyword within the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **updateEmailAllProcessing** to return a promise so you can await on it. and resolve the promise with the result inside the callback.

```
async updateEmailAllProcessing()
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let result: boolean;
    let alert = this.mesService.emailChangeConfirmation();
    alert.present();
    alert.onDidDismiss((data) => {
      console.log('data->', data);
      if (data) {
        let alert1 = this.mesService.passwordPrompt();
        alert1.present();
        alert1.onDidDismiss(data1 => {
          console.log('password->', data1);
          if (data1) {
            this.authServ.reauthenticateUser(data1).then(() => {
              console.log('User Reauth Done');
              resolve(true);
            })
          }
          else
            resolve(false);
        })
      }
      else
        resolve(false);
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: It resovled my problem!! great answer sir :)

Comment: Thanks, happy to help :)